# Solution of Abel type integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

I would like to know when (for what functions $f$) and how I can find integrable solution of equation
\begin{align}
f(x)=\int_x^{\infty}\frac{u(y)}{\sqrt{y-x}} \ dy,
\end{align}
where $u$ is unknown function?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. Consider adding some more context/background on what you already know, or any work you've tried (if anything) to assist those here in helping you.

Comment: You need some conditions on the function $u$.

Comment: What kind of conditions on $u$ are useful in knowing a solution exists?

Comment: @patric, perhaps my question and solution might be relevant to you, see  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757692/help-with-variant-of-abels-integral